# Passing Forms a parameter and calling its events

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, methods

MDIParent (frmMain) form is the main window with a menu strip with 3 menu items namely , frmSales, frmProducts, frmCustomers. each one being a form i need to call as modal , and not instantiate every time it is called. i have successfully done this, however i would like to create a method that takes the form name as parameter, but i also need to call the respective FormClose event for whichever form i pass into it.

This is the code in frmMain i am trying to minimize by simply calling a method every time the menu strip item is selected.Just to be clear, the code i have is working like intended, but id like to see a method created for this.

Ihe following is typed in notepad from memory, so there might be some errors, but you will understand it nonetheless:

```
frmSales SalesForm;
frmProducts ProductsForm;
frmCustomers CustormersForm;

private void ShowChildFormModal (Form myFormName)
{
    if(myFormName = null)
    {
        myFormName= new myFormName(); // is this correct ?
        myFormName.MDIParent = this; // referring to frMain - MDIParent

        // now i need to call the OnClosed Event for the form in the 
        // parameter so i can set it to null :
        myFormName_FormClose += EventHandler (FormClosed, EventArgs)  
        myFormName.Show()
    }
    else
    {
        myFormName.Activate();
    }
}

private void frmSales_OnClosed (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SalesForm = null;
}

private void frmProducts_OnClosed (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProductsForm = null;
}

private void frmCustomers_OnClosed (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CustomersForm = null;
}
```

Comment: _"the following is typed in notepad from memory"_ - don't do that. Make sure you post a [mcve].

Comment: My apologies for that , i am sitting at work , not related to coding at all , and was thinking about a solution and also decided to ask here . but if i try to explain it , somebody would ask to see the code , so i typed the code from memory as best i could.

Comment: Is this asp.net code?

Comment: c# windows app - visual studio 2015

Answer (score 1):

You can use dictionary with form name and their representing form as below :

```
SalesForm salesForm = new SalesForm();
ProuctsForm productForm = new ProuctsForm();
CustormersForm customerForm = new CustormersForm();



Dictionary <string,Form> MyForms = new Dictionary<string,Form>();

MyForms["sales"] = salesForm;

MyForms["products"] = productForm;

MyForms["customer"] = customerForm;

// Set Your properties and events you want here

private void ShowChildFormModal (string myFormName)
{
    if(myFormName = null && MyForms[myFormName] !=null)
    {       
        MyForms[myFormName].MDIParent = this; // referring to frMain - MDIParent

        MyForms[myFormName].myFormName_FormClose += EventHandler (FormClosed, EventArgs)  ;
        MyForms[myFormName].ShowModal();
    }
    else
    {
        // Else what you need to do ??
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thats an interesting solution . ill try that and give you feedback with the results , this time ill copy the code and the results :)

Comment: great waiting to see what did you reach

Comment: comparing the code i posted to yours , what am i doing wrong ? reason i ask is , i am passing a Form object as a parameter . how is my method different to yours ?

Comment: your calling the parameter myFormName which actually the form name to be string and how it will be retrieved, you dont need the form object any more as parameter just by the name you will get the required form inside the method

Comment: but if i have a string as the parameter , how do i call the event for the form inside the method?   or is that the reason you would use the string name as a key to the form in the dictionary ?

Comment: here come the role of the dictionary in 4th line, you give it the name of the form that is passed, it will give you the Form object which you registered, and you can do with it all what you want.

Comment: :) great hope it helped, if yes don't forget to mark it

Comment: Hi , so after trying your code , after a few changes and figuring a few things out to make it work , it does not allow me to ope the form as modal , it simply instantiates the form. you will notice in your code snippet, you are not instantiating the form at all , so the first time the form is called, it gives me an error , object not instantiated. as soon as i instantiate the form inside the method , the compiler complains about the double ampersand in the if statement. i could not get it to work due to my limited knowledge of available possibilities. i will keep looking for another solution.

Comment: I just wrote you sample code that give you the idea of retrieving the form by name. The code doesn't do anything else. But I will edit now to init the forms for you and set some events also, to be modal you need to change the message from show to showmodal updated in code also

Comment: if anything else tell me i will guide you step by step

Comment: i will try that and let you know.